# What would happen if 'The One' died prematurely? The Matrix

Tags: the-matrix

### What would happen if 'The One' died before fulfilling the prophecy?

I understand that in the Matrix 'The One' seems to be for all accounts immortal, but what I am curious to is if he were to say die in an accident in Zion or maybe he was murdered by someone, like agent smith was trying to do. We know he can die as he did when fight the last battle, so he is in that respect the same as everyone else in the real world.

Being that the Matrix needs the anomaly to restore balance,

> ***The Architect:*** As I was saying, she stumbled upon a solution whereby
>   nearly ninety-nine percent of the test subjects accepted the program
>   provided they were given a choice - even if they were only aware of it
>   at a near-unconscious level. While this solution worked, it was
>   fundamentally flawed, creating the otherwise contradictory systemic
>   anomaly, that, if left unchecked, might threaten the system itself.
>   Ergo, those who refused the program, while a minority, would
>   constitute an escalating probability of disaster.
>
> ***Neo:*** This is about Zion.

---

> ***Neo:*** Why am I here?
>
> ***The Architect:*** Your life is the sum of a
>   remainder of an unbalanced equation inherent to the programming of the
>   matrix. You are the eventuality of an anomaly, which despite my
>   sincerest efforts I have been unable to eliminate from what is
>   otherwise a harmony of mathematical precision. While it remains a
>   burden assiduously avoided, it is not unexpected, and thus not beyond
>   a measure of control. Which has led you, inexorably, here.
>
> ***Neo:*** You haven't answered my question.
>
> ***The Architect:*** Quite right. Interesting. That was quicker than the others.

---

> ***The Architect:*** The function of the One is now to return to the source,
>   allowing a temporary dissemination of the code you carry, reinserting
>   the prime program. After which you will be required to select from the
>   matrix 23 individuals, 16 female, 7 male, to rebuild Zion. Failure to
>   comply with this process will result in a cataclysmic system crash
>   killing everyone connected to the matrix, which coupled with the
>   extermination of Zion will ultimately result in the extinction of the
>   entire human race.
>
> ***Neo:*** You won't let it happen, you can't. You need
>   human beings to survive.
>
> ***The Architect:*** There are levels of survival
>   we are prepared to accept.

So the systemic anomaly manifests and is produced when the time is right, so if that person was to die like I said earlier, would another anomaly be born, or would 'The One's' powers be transferred to what you would call a backup? Which I would not think would be far from the truth, as there are all those kids at the Oracle's residence waiting to see if they were 'The One' due to the powers that had???

Was there anything mentioned in a back story or something like that?

Comment: @Valorum, Just curious, does an answer that may provide an answer to a different question regarded a dupe? The wording of a dupe states that, `This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.` Would that make this a non dupe?

Comment: Where a high quality *answer* to another question exactly answers another question, that's also a dupe.